# Visual Studio 2019. Не создаются автоматически представления и контроллер

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019

При попытке сгенерить новый контроллер с представлениями с использованием Модели (без модели-работает), процесс останавливается на:

> Finding the generator 'controller'...
>  Running the generator
>   'controller'...
>  Attempting to compile the application in
>   memory.
>     at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.b__6_0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[]
>   args)
>     at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[]
>   args)
>     at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[]
>   args)

- И ничего не происходит.
- VS2019 версия 16.3.4.
- Проект ASP NET CORE MVC.
- NET CORE 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Метод `Main` содержал `async`. Убрал асинхронный метод - всё заработало.